# Preg match and filtering results by PHP

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-match

I have something like this in one my rows

```
[0] -> * Row: {{t|fa|kuinka}}, {{t+|ti|miten}}, {{t|fi|millä tavalla|sc=Hani}}, {{t+|fi|millä tavalla|sc=Hani|sc=Td}}
```

How can I get these like this one?

```
[0] ->  fa|kuinka; ti|miten; fi|millä tavalla; fi|millä tavalla
```

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: Trying but no success, always have problem with preg :P

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a `preg_match_all` call with a pattern like this:

```
{{[t+]{1,2}\|([^}\|]*)\|([^}\|]*)[\|]?([^}\|]+)[\|]?([^}\|]+)}}
```

Then you can obtain te single pieces from the resulting array, see the docs: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php